# runtime made changes to dataset in c#.net

Tags: c#

Hello any body help me on dataset changes accepting at runtime?

The Problem is

Step 1 I am getting data from database to dataset

Step 2 In this dataset I want to change one column value and display the changed value in grid view 
here is my code:

```
ds = dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_GetTranGridWithIMGEX");
for (int j=0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
{
    string DecryptText = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][3].ToString().Trim();
    MessageBox.Show(DecryptText);
    string AfterDecrypText = DecryptString(DecryptText);
    MessageBox.Show(AfterDecrypText);
    ds.AcceptChanges();
}

dgvSummary.DataSource = ds;
dgvSummary.DataMember = "Table";
dgvSummary.Columns[11].Visible = false;
dgvSummary.Columns[13].Visible = false;
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're not updating the DataSet, so there are no changes to accept.

Add this line:

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][3] = AfterDecryptText;
```

Then call ds.AcceptChanges().

Also, once you set the DataSource on the GridView, don't forget to call `dgvSummary.DataBind()`.

Comment: Thank u Somach Sir it is working well.But i d'nt find the dgvsummary.databind().But instead of that method intelesence showing .DataBindings(),DataBindingCompleate().So Now What to Do Curently Iam